# Is there that I can continue my HTML code in another page, while being in the main code?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there that I can continue my HTML code in another page, while being in the main code?

For example, in HTML you can make 1000 extra pages of JS and just use something like

```
<script src="js/example.js"></script>
```

to make the HTML page look cleaner, and less obstructed by the extra JS code,
is there a way I can do that to continue adding more HTML elements to another page while using the same stuff from my main page?

im writing a lot of HTML and don't want to make the main page too messy

Comment: Consider using React with JSX for writing HTML like components

Comment: you could write your own js that would retrieve html via ajax, the biggest issue here would be how to piece it together at the end. You would either have to wait until your entire document was loaded to put it into the DOM or have some template system defining where content should end up. I think you're better off using a PHP or RUBY based (or equivalent server language) templating engine which would do the same thing without the nuisance of network calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#idofDiv').load('file.html');
```

Comment: You will use that jquery code to load the html file into a <div> on your main index.html      <div id="idofDiv"></div>

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your file to `filename.php`, you can use an include function. The code should look like this:

```
<?php

include 'header.html';

?>
```

You should probably put the files on the body. Just a warning: PHP is hard to learn at first, especially because you have to host a server and do many other things. To learn more about the subject, visit these sites:

[W3schools PHP tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

[XXAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using .php and using php include.

Comment: This is about as thin of an answer as it gets. You should elaborate on what you're referring to.

Comment: Care to explain this answer?

Comment: Gangsters like me don't need to explain!