# Have a number of seperate HTML pages within one file

Tags: html

I would like about 10-15 seperate pages on one HTML file. I have seen that you can use JS to do this by showing/hiding the divs, but I am not sure if this work with a large number of pages. Is there another solution you can suggest that will work in my circumstances? Any help would be greatly appreciated

I would like to have a navbar on the side containing links to 10-15 pages. I would like for these pages to be accessed without having to reload the page. As well, there would be a dashboard that acts as the home page, with links to the pages that can also be accessed by the navbar. I am struggling to see how to complete the multiple pages within one html file element.

Comment: Best to define exactly what you mean with file, html page and how they relate to each-other through the URLs used to access it all.
If you're unsure, best to define what you want as the user experience and what you already have as content.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: This may have been previously answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744496/is-there-that-i-can-continue-my-html-code-in-another-page-while-being-in-the-ma/47746073#47746073)

Answer (score -1):

Generally doing this the way you describe it, *cramming 15 static pages into one `.html` file*, is considered a *bad practice*.

However, if you are referring to something like a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), then it's very common and can easily be done in JavaScript frameworks such as [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)'s [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) or in [React](https://reactjs.org/)'s [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). A simple router can also be written in plain vanilla JS like [this one](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/A-modern-JavaScript-router-in-100-lines-history-api-pushState-hash-url).

Depending on what exactly you are trying to do you may also want to check out HTML template processors. My favorite of them all is [Pug](https://pugjs.org/). HTML template processors can be very powerful and let you do whole range of cool things. It can let you have a single file just for the navigation that is inserted into all your main pages. I use it all the time!

I hope some of this helps you! Thanks!